# How to drop multiple databases in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2

Is it possible to drop multiple databases in Hive?
How to see the comment given for table, describe not showing it?

and also with primitive data type how to use where clause?

Answer (score -1):

Query-1 Solution:

Yes i think we can drop multiple databases in hive. check in below

Drop a database :

hive> drop database sampledb3;
OK
Time taken: 1.036 seconds

Drop multiple databases in Hive

hive> drop databases like 's*';

need to check this.

Query-2 Solution:

To check for the comments for a given table :

hive> describe extended employees;

this will definitely give the description details.

Comment: drop databases is not supported by Hive.